# Controlling Angular Directive From Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a angular directive which acts like a login popup.This directive opens a  popup page.

```
modal = angular.module('Directive.Modal',[]);



modal.directive('modalLogin',function()
{   
    return {

      restrict: 'EA',
      scope:true,
      scope :
      {
        header : "=",
        callback : "&",
        email : "=",
        password : "=",
        button : "=",
        show : "&"
      },
      templateUrl: 'directiveTemplate/modalWelcome.html',
      link : function(scope,element,attrs)
      {
            scope.$watch("show",function()
            {
                console.log("Inner Function Clicked");

            });
       }

      }


});
```

However after using bootstrap.ui i see i can call modals using one liner directly from my controllers. This is something that i would like to achieve as how can i create modals /custom modals using one liner from controllers.

The below code is in my html

```
<!-- Login PopUP Modal Directive -->
<modal-login 
header="ModalPageHeader"  
email="ModalPageEmail"
password="ModalPagePass"
button="ModalPageButton"
ng-click="getAuth()" 
></modal-login>
```

The below is the code in the controller

```
app.controller('indexGlobalCtrl', function($scope,$location,ngDialog) {


    $scope.ModalPageHeader ="Login Page";
    $scope.ModalPageEmail ="Username As E-Mail";
    $scope.ModalPagePass = "Password";
    $scope.ModalPageButton = "Login";

 //   $scope.dismiss();


    $scope.getAuth = function()
    {
        alert("sd");
        $scope.show = !$scope.show;

    };
}
```

This is the directive i have created. though i can use ng-show and ng-hide but my requirements is to create a one liner API which one toggle modal.
1. How can i control it programatically

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need not create a directive to open a modal.You can open it from a controller by using $modal.open() as mentioned in angular ui.bootstrap
Here is the link for the angular ui.bootstrap documentation https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is i have a modal writteen using twtiier bootstrap and directive. i need something like bootstrap.ui modal . Is it possible that i create something like that

Comment: It wont affect you structure.It uses the same classes as used in twitter bootstrap